# how to include wlan_logs in bugreport

Tags: android, tcpdump

I need tcpdump pcap files, but found that not all devices have this, is there any switcher in developer config ? I have tried setting log level to verbose, but still not work, what can I do next, thx! [I think I have descripted my problem clearly, but system need 220 characters, ):]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`*#*#9434#*#*` works well in Xiaomi's devices; `tcpdump.pcap*` will be found in `*unziped bugreport files dir*/common/wlan_logs`